# How to use readline bindings everywhere?

Tags: linux, readline, nixos, inputrc

Using OSX I am able to use readline-specific bindings, such as going to the beginning of the line with <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd>, everywhere. I recently switched to Linux (specifically NixOS) and I've been missing this behavior a lot when using applications such as Firefox.

I've read these shortcuts come from the `GNU Readline` library, so I tried setting up a few bindings using an `.inputrc` file in my home folder to no avail.

So my question is: can I set up my system to use these bindings everywhere?